# Send POST Batch Request From PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, http-post, batch-processing, measurement-protocol

[Measurement protocol docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch) give me these directions to send a batch request:

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fabout
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fcontact
```

Im a little confused on how i would build my url for this?

What i have tried:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$guzzle->request('POST','www.google-analytics.com/batch',[
                'query' =>  "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event
                             v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event
                             v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event
                             v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event
                             v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event"
            ]);
```

This does not work, there should 5 new events in ga, but i only receive 1 (the first one).

How can i send a batch request to the measurement protocol?

Comment: What you want, is the `curl_multi_*` family. Which seems not to be wrapped by Laracurl, at first sight.

Comment: im having the same issue, im confused because the docs kinda state that you should send the same keys consecutively. So order would matter? Usually the way to do this would be `v[0]=1&t[0]=event...v[1]=1&t[1]=pageview` but the batch protocol just line-separates the post data?

Comment: @eyecatchUp please post an answer if you know a way

Comment: First try things with https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Comment: @Vineet1982 i have it does not allow for batch request testing from what i can see. I can send single request just fine, but batch does not seem to work, i cant understand what google docs is asking for in there request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `GuzzleHttp`, you should use `body` instead of `query`:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$guzzle->request('POST','www.google-analytics.com/batch', [
        'body' => implode("\n", array(
                        'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event',
                        'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event',
                        'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event',
                        'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event',
                        'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=event',
        )]);
```

Comment: For some reason, I had to specify a `null` User-Agent in `headers`. (for reference, Guzzle was setting `User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.1 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.4.3`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe urls need to be in the data part, not in the header part of request ?

So use the second post parameter of laracurl (from [Laracurl README](https://github.com/bbrink68/Laracurl/blob/2.0.0/README.md)):

```
 $response = Laracurl::post($url, ['post' => $data]);
```

with :

```
 $data = join("\n",array(
      "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome",
      "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fabout",
      "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fcontact"));
```

Comment: Laracurl documentation seems to be lacking detail. Check source code of Laracurl::post to know how second parameter is used.

Answer (score -1):

Hoping help someone:  **Analytics Management API v3**

Creating a new goal

(PHP Google_Client, Google_Service_Analytics)

```
/*
    Assuming there is a $goals array
*/

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->addScope([Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY,
                    Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_EDIT]);

$client->setDeveloperKey($API_KEY);
$client->setSubject($EMAIL);  
$client->refreshToken($REFRESH_TOKEN);

$client->setUseBatch(true);
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);     
$batch = $analytics->createBatch();

foreach($goals as $goal){

    $req1 = $analytics->management_goals->insert(XXXXXX, UA-XXXXXX-1, XXXXXX, $goal);
    $batch->add($req1);
}

try {
        $batchResponse = $batch->execute();
        /* Handling Response */
        foreach ($batchResponse as $key => $value) {

            if(!($value instanceof Google_Service_Exception)){
                echo $value->getId()."\n";
                continue;
            }
            print_r($value->getErrors());

        }
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    /*
        handling exception  
    */
}
```